# The best place to store Google service account JSON file?

Tags: docker, google-play-services, google-kubernetes-engine

Current setup: using Docker to generate the image of the application, deploy the image via Google Container Engine (GKE).

It is not ideal to have Google service account JSON file in the code and later on wrap it into the image. Is there any other way to store the JSON file?